# Creating a policy to allow update, create and delete elastic-beanstalk environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I need to create an IAM custom permission policy that grants to create, update and delete **elastic-beanstalk** environment variables. Could you guys please help me to figure out how to do this? My user group already have grant to read all elastic beans settings but when trying to edit a elastic environment variable it throws bellow error message:

Validation Error
User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:user/XXXXX is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:ValidateConfigurationSettings on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2:XXXXXX:environment/XXXXXXX

[image]

Comment: Can you post the custom policy?

Comment: I don' see an action there regarding the editing of the env vars. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awselasticbeanstalk.html

Comment: @Spiff The custom policy has just some settings I have been testing with no success. Im testing some of these Actions listed by AWS documentation. I gonna post here if I succeed..